# No route able to invoke action Security.authenticate was found

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I've written an own security class, derived from the security module. 
part of my routes-table looks like this:

```
*       /authenticate           Security.authenticate
```

and my template looks like this:

```
<form action="@{Security.authenticate()}" method="POST">
<label for="user">E-Mail:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
   <label>password:</label>    <input type="password" name="password" size="19"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Signin" />
</form>
```

I'm getting the following exception:

No route able to invoke action Security.authenticate was found.

In /app/views/Security/index.html (around line 11)

```
<form action="@{Security.authenticate()}" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you show us the signature of `authenticate(...)` please ? Play might need some arguments to build the route properly, depending of what you have there.

Make sure your route is specified before an overriding one. For example :

```
*     /authenticate                            Security.authenticate
*     /{controller}/{action}                   {controller}.{action}
```

Putting the second line before the first one, results in your route being mapped to /security/authenticate instead of /authenticate.